# War on Britain's Roads docu review

Tags: feature-request, blog

Did anybody who contributes to the Blogoverflow blog for bicycles see the "[War on Britain's Roads](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b01p7q2l)" documentary?  If so would you be willing to write a review of it for the blog?

Comment: If you'd like to contribute to the blog, I'd be happy to set you up with a blog account.

Comment: That'd be cool, but I'm not much of a blogger.  Besides, apart from one particular part I didn't think it was as bad as everyone else seems to so I'm very much in the minority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I watched the programme last night, and I'd be happy to write a blog on it.

If anyone else would like to voice their opinion on the programme we could go for some kind of joint effort on it.

**Update** - I've written the blog now.

Comment: Looks pretty good. Maybe expand the acronyms (like HGV)? I think a mod needs to "publish" it for you. Want me to do that right away?

Comment: Thanks, I've had one last edit and I think it's good to go now.

Comment: Ok, it's published now.